# Mining solution found

Tags: mining, mining-pools, ethminer, solo-mining

I've just started mining with a gtx 1070, and following a guide on the web I've set everything up, using a pool (nanopool).
Watching the result of the mining program I noticed alread 3 times that I found a solution, here is the screenshot:

[image]

So that means that my GPU found the solution of the block? It's strange to me to get 3 solution (should be 15 ether reward right?) in 30 minutes, it would be way too lucky imo.. Or am I missing something?

Also if I would like to mining in solo instead of pool, how should I set my  ethminer command line?

Comment: How much is a share worth ? I just tested mining and found 2 Valid Shares (whatever this exactly means). How much do I get for participating. Can someone explain that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you are mining as part of a pool (nanopool), with that being said, any blocks found by the pool are mined collectively and the reward (5 ETH for a block + transaction fees or uncles) is distributed or shared amongst pool miners proportional to the hashing power contributed by each miner. The solutions you find are part of a bigger solution.

When solo mining however, you would get the whole reward (5 ETH for a block + transaction fees or uncles). I hope this helps.

The key is : difference between Pool and Solo mining.

Comment: If I'm mining in a pool (ethermine.org) and it says "solution found" does that mean I solved the entire block? Or, just a small part of it that was sent back to the pool? I've seen "solution found" at least 6 times since I started mining a week ago, so I'm assuming it's just a small piece of the larger block?

Comment: Quite right, just a small part of the solution. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You found a solution to a given *pool share* not a full block.
If you were solo it would mean a block.
It doesn't.
Just a completed share for the pool that gave it to you.
Miner doesn't know the difference or care.

Answer (score 0):

With the current difficulty of finding a solution this question answers itself. No way you are finding blocks there.